# Persisting IS08601 date format using Joda and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jodatime

I am trying to persist date entered by my app users in ISO8601 format, so I've build a custom Hibernate mapping class as follows:

```
public class UTCTimestampType extends org.hibernate.type.TimestampType{ 
    @Override
    public Object get(ResultSet rs, String name) throws SQLException {
        return rs.getTimestamp(name, createUTCCalendar());
    }
    private static Calendar createUTCCalendar() {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTimeZone(new SimpleTimeZone(0, "UTC"));
        return c;
    }
    @Override
    public void set(PreparedStatement st, Date value, int index)
            throws SQLException{
        Timestamp ts;
        if (value instanceof Timestamp) {
            ts = (Timestamp) value;
        } else {
            ts = new Timestamp(((java.util.Date)value).getTime());
        }
        st.setTimestamp(index, ts, createUTCCalendar());
    }   
}
```

Then in my entity class I defined the date field as follows:

```
    @Type(type="com.domainname.empmgmt.common.util.UTCTimestampType")
@Column(name="DOB",nullable=false,unique=false)
private DateTime dob;
```

When I tried saving the date from the controller using following code:

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Hong_Kong" );
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "MM/dd/yyyy" ).withZone( timeZone );
String input = "05/05/2013"; //For testing...
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime( input );
employee.setDob(dateTime);
```

I get the following error:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: org.joda.time.DateTime cannot be cast to
>   java.util.Date

I am not sure why the custom mapping is not working as the error shows that Hibernate still sees the field as java.util.Date and not as DateTime, so can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here and how to resolve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your custom type set() method expects a Date as value to persist:

```
public void set(PreparedStatement st, Date value, int index)
```

But your field is of type `DateTime`, which does not extend Date. So obviously, that can't work.

Comment: Well Date is not my choice here it must be Date as I am inheriting from org.hibernate.type.TimestampType

Comment: Tried using set(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index) but it never compiled TimestampType inherits from AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType, please check http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/TimestampType.html

Comment: That's the problem. Don't extend from TimestampType, since TimestampType is a `AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<Date>`, and you want a `AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<DateTime>`.

Comment: So how I am going to make custom mapping in hibernate to save DateTime instead of Date? Actually all I care about is saving the date in ISO8601 format, so is there a way I can do so without all the custom mapping work, I will be glad to follow it, but as far as I've researched the only approach is to persist the date as DateTime instead of Date

Comment: I would use [jadira](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/), which does all that for you. Otherwise, copy and paste the code of TimestampType, and adapt it to make it accept a DateTime instead of a Date.

Comment: Even though jadira looks promising, their documentation is very weak and I am worried after depending on them in code with future upgrades in Hibernate a problem happens, exactly like that with TimestampType, as in earlier versions of Hibernate it used to accept Object instead of Date which was going to solve the problem but in recent versions of Hibernate it now uses Date only...I am sorry I am not following what do you mean by copy and paste the code of TimestampType can you please elaborate what do you meany by copy and paste the code here? Thanks

Comment: You open the file TimestampType.java, which is part of the open-source Hibernate code. Then you copy all the text and paste it into your DateTimeType.java source file. Then you adapt the code to make it use DateTime instead of Date, until it compiles and does what you want.

Comment: Still the class will be inheriting from AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType unless I go and change code all the way up the tree, sounds like complicated approach. I am thinking would it be better to save the date in millesconds as Integer in DB then convert it using Joda to whatever time zone the user have?

Comment: Well, it should inherit from `AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<DateTime>`. Not from `AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<Date>`. The generic `<Date>` type is precisely the problem here.

Comment: As I can see from TimestampType.java there is a lot Date objects, so I am wondering shall I change all or just the AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<Date> one?

Comment: As I've mentioned earlier, the moment I tried changing AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<Date> to AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<DateTime> I get error: The constructor AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<DateTime>(TimestampTypeDescriptor, JdbcTimestampTypeDescriptor) is undefined in TimestampType constructor, so I have to go all the way up the tree to change every Date to DateTime....which sounds like really complicated approach and can possibly cause a lot of problems.

Comment: The goal of TimestampType is to persist an object of type Date as a java.sql.Timestamp. Your goal is to persist an object of type DateTime as a java.sql.Timestamp. So, replace every occurrence of Date by DateTime, and make the code compile. Read the api doc of the classes and methods you're implementing to understand what they're supposed to do.

Comment: JB Nizet, a lot of errors started appearing beside the one mentioned earlier due to incompatibility between DateTime and other types, example Timestamp and so on. Are you sure copying the TimestampType approach works?!

Comment: This answer really didn't help in anyway, I have read the API doc for this specific class and reading it didn't change the fact that I have to change a lot of super classes in order to copy this class, I am sorry but I couldn't find your reply helpful

Comment: It works if you understand what you're doing, and implement the additional required types (JdbcTimestampTypeDescriptor should also be rewritten). You're choosing the hard way by wanting to implement that all by yourself instead of picking a library that has already implemented it and tested it for you. So yes, it requires a little bit of work. I won't do this work for you. But if you're not ready to understand generics and understand the design and all you need to do it, then don't do it, and use jadira.

Comment: Well, that's what I said in the beginning that your approach of copying the class is over-complicated for the task I want. Using a framework which you've suggested is not the ultimate solution also as while upgrading Hibernate to higher versions there is a BIG chance a break of incompatibility happens in the future and I end up starting from square one again! Specially if we considered the recommended framework poor documentation and support!

Comment: I didn't ask you to do this work for me, all I am asking is for a reliable solution, not a recommendation to choose between two non reliable approaches! :)

Comment: There are two possible approaches: use a library, and implement it yourself. You chose to refuse the first, easy one. And despite the explanation I gave you on why your code doesn't work and how you might do to implement it without reinventing the wheel, by mimicking existing, similar code, you find it too hard. What's left?

Comment: What's left is the first approach have very poor documentation, please re-check their website some pages are simply empty :) So using a framework with no documentation is like shooting in the dark I have to speculate what the original developer wanted to do, that is just as a start....now imagine the horror if a problem happened while using this framework OR worse if Hibernate upgraded and the framework didn't upgrade it with them. You see it is not about just finding a solution, it is about finding a solution you can depend on...you are experienced dev and I am sure you know what I mean

Comment: Just for the record I have no problem using any framework, library or anything that can make my life easier here, after all I am not trying to re-invent the wheel....I just need something reliable that won't cause me a lot of trouble. I've given a simple example before on trouble caused by upgrade in hibernate version

Comment: Then read, understand and document the jadira code, or rewrite it by yourself. If Hibernate decides to release a new, backward-incompatible version, there's a much higher chance of the jadira code to be quickly updated than your own code to magically work with the new backward-incompatible version.

Comment: I am sorry if my message wasn't clear enough in the begining, Jadira have very limited documentation to get you started with their framework, to get started I must read each and every class in their framework and start thinking how they work together, is this what you are recommending as fast solution to the problem?

Comment: You put the jar in the classpath, and annotate your DateTime field as shown in http://jadira.sourceforge.net/usertype-userguide.html. Of course, you choose the appropriate type depending on your actual field type and your requirements, by picking in http://jadira.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/jadira/usertype/dateandtime/joda/package-summary.html. Each type explains what type it persists, in which type of column, and how. It's as simple as that.

Comment: After spending 2 hours trying to fix tons of errors (incompatibility with other packages, @Column definition...etc) I faced just by adding the Jadira dependency to my Spring MVC pom.xml and up to this momeent it is simply not working :( Now assuming I faced more serious problem, where can I get support if the framework don't have a forum or any kind of support? I have installed, configured many frameworks, libraries but I must admit this by all means is not easy as you have claimed and as their website claim

Comment: IMHO using this package is not a good idea, a framework with no support is a total waste of time even if it has good libraries

Comment: I'm using it in several projects, and it's as simple as that. How about describing your problem, rather than saying "it doesn't work"?